# How Select a value from column in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

In Column consist of values

```
C1         C2
1         1235
1         4578
1         4177
2         1427
2         1427
2         1427
2        [{"label":"2 Bed, 1 Bathroom"Woodland Tow]
```

in spark, if i use below code

```
DataFrame df1=df.groupBy("C1").agg(functions.max("C2");
```

Output gives

```
  C1        C2
    1        4578
    2        [{"label":"2 Bed, 1 Bathroom"Woodland Tow]
```

But I need

```
C1        C2
1        4578
2        1427
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert here, so more of common sense guidance:

```
DataFrame df1=df.groupBy("C1").agg(functions.max("C2");
```

obviously invokes some `functions.max()` utility that looks for a max in that column. And that `max()` computes the wrong result for your string values.

Conclusion: you probably have to use a different method to compute that maximum. I guess a naive approach would be to define `specialMax()`:

- if the column value represents a parseable number: then parse the number and use that for comparison
- otherwise, represent that column value with -1

When then use that `specialMax()` method, you should get the largest number you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the max value only for integer values, simply cast your column to "int" first and then perform the grouping.

```
df.withColumn("C2", col("C2").cast("int")).groupBy("C1").agg(max("C2"))
```